# "Android SDK: Manage add-on sites" won't reload user-defined site after eclipse re-install

Tags: android, eclipse, add-on, failed-installation, hidden-files

I recently had to completely re-install eclipse (e.g. androideclipse installed from http://www.android.com/).  Before my re-install I happened to be using a user-defined add-on site  ( e.g. https://broadcom-ble.googlecode.com/files/repository.xml)   Everything worked as expected before the re-install.

After the re-install, when I try to reload the same add-on, the SDK Mgr appears to accept the pointer, but doesn't add it.  (Progress bar starts briefly and then goes away, and when I compile, the compiler can't find the import.)  Clearly there is some leftover state that I have not expunged before re-installing.  I have deleted, cleaned and restarted the androideclipse install seven times now being increasingly fastidious about deleting all possible eclipse files first.

I have deleted *every scrap* of eclipse installation I can find including .eclipse, .android and .metadata.  So I suspect there must be some other fossil file lying around.

Clearly I am missing so bit of magic.  Does some guru out there know of a list of files that have to be removed to make the machine "clean".  Is there some registry entry - surely not.

Answer (score 0):

The user-defined site (https://broadcom-ble.googlecode.com/files/repository.xml) library depends upon Android 2.3.3(**API10**) and unless you have already *expanded* API10 in the SDK Manager to reveal API10's sub-components you won't see the new component appear.  So you sit and wonder in frustration why it has not loaded.

The wise make sure they select "Package/Sort by Repository" in the main SDK pane.  Then when you have finished specifying the user-defined site, and return to the main SDK manager panel, the new component is not hidden under an unexpanded API level.

Now when you check the new component and click install, the "licensing dialog" appears and it mentions that it depends upon some other package - (e.g. Android 2.2. API10 rev2) which is the big clue.